# Helm chart. I cannot send a command to the container via --set

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

In deployment.yaml in:

```
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.stand }}-container
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          {{- if $.Values.command }}
          command:
            {{ .Values.command.cmd }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if or $.Values.env $.Values.envSecrets }}
```

I tried adding:

```
{{- if $.Values.command }}
command:
  {{ .Values.command.cmd }}
{{- end }}
```

Then I tried to pass the command:

```
helm install NAME nexus/stand 
      --set 'command.cmd[0]=- /bin/sh' \
      --set 'command.cmd[1]=- -с' \
      --set 'command.cmd[2]=- |' \
      --set 'command.cmd[3]=while true; do' \
      --set 'command.cmd[4]=sleep 60;' \
      --set 'command.cmd[5]=done'
```

but nothing works.

How to via --set pass?

```
command:
- /bin/sh
- -c
- |
  while true; do
    sleep 60;
  done
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helm does not support setting non-existent array elements, you can assign values by passing the entire array or set the corresponding number of elements first, and then modify it by --set cmd[i]=xxx.

---

First of all, in the deployment.yaml file, the `Values.command.cmd` field should not be quoted directly, as an array needs to be quoted in the following way: `{{ toYaml … }}`

deployment.yaml

```yaml
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.stand }}-container
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          {{- if $.Values.command }}
          command:
            {{ toYaml .Values.command.cmd | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if or $.Values.env $.Values.envSecrets }}
```

Then if you use the values.yaml file method to pass in the parameters, you should write like this here：

values.yaml

```yaml
command:
  cmd:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - while true; do sleep 60; done
```

Finally, if you want to set by `--set`, you need to pass array values you can use curly braces (unix shell require quotes):

```yaml
--set command.cmd={"/bin/sh"\,"-c"\,"while true; do sleep 60; done"}
```

**Notice!!!**

The separator of the array elements `,` you must remember to add a `\`